# How do I make function execute after a specific page finished loading

Tags: javascript, html

I am making a quiz which includes 1 page for each question and I'm trying to make a well done message show on the screen and disappear after a set amount of time when you get a correct question AKA when you go to the next page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>test</title>
    <script src="scripts.js"> </script>
</head>
<body id="body1">
    <h1> 1 </h1>
    <p>  QUESTION </p>
    <button onclick="location.href = '1.html';hideRightAnswerFinal();" id="a"> PLACE HOLDER </button>
    <button onclick="wrongAnswer()"> PLACE HOLDER </button>
    <p id="output">  </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Second Question Page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>test</title>
    <script src="scripts.js"> </script>
</head>
<body id="body2">
    <h3 id="welldone"> Well Done </h3>
    <h1> 2 </h1>
    <p>  QUESTION </p>
    <button onclick="location.href = '2.html';hideRightAnswerFinal();" id="b"> PLACE HOLDER </button>
    <button onclick="wrongAnswer()"> PLACE HOLDER </button>
    <button onclick="location.href = 'index.html';goBackHide();"> Go back </button>
    <p id="output"> </p>
</body>
</html>
```

My Java Script. I tried making the message show and disappear if the specific body is loaded. As you can see, that didn't work.

```
const wrong = "Wrong, try again!";
function wrongAnswer() {
    document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = wrong
}
function hide() {
    document.getElementById('welldone').innerHTML = "";
}
function hideRightAnswer() {
    setTimeout(hide, 500)
}
function hideRightAnswerFinal() {
    document.getElementById('body2').onload = hideRightAnswer;
}
function goBackHide() {
    document.getElementById('welldone').innerHTML = "";
}
```

Im very new to java script and this is my first time trying to do anything like this

I have tried using .onload to make the functions execute only when that specific body is loaded because what I think is happening is that the scripts are executing before the page even loads.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I also forgot to mention that I also want to make well done not show up at all when using the goBack function.

Comment: To make things less confusing you could load a different script on each page (since you're new to JS).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you need exactly, but try to use `document.onreadystatechange`

```
document.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (document.readyState == "interactive") {
        // Do something.
    }
}
```

Any code inside this function will run after your page is fully loaded